# What does friendship level do?

Tags: genshin-impact

I've seen in the menus that each character, except the traveler, has a 'friendship' level. It seems to be linked to how long the character has been in the active party and, if I read right, caps at 10.

But what does it actually do?

Comment: Friendship level isn't directly linked to the time a character has been in the party, it's linked to how much companionship EXP is received while the character is in the party. For example, if I used Ayaka to defeat a boss but swapped her out for Ganyu before I claimed the reward, Ganyu would receive the companionship EXP - not Ayaka, even though she would've been in the party for longer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Raising a character's friendship level:

- Unlocks more of their lore/background story and voice lines (accessible via the Profile section on the Character screen);
- Unlocks more interactions with the character when they are set as a companion in your Serenitea Pot;
- Unlocks more facial expressions that you can choose when taking a photo;
- Gives you the character's namecard that you can set on your profile once you reach friendship level 10.

Additionally, you will earn achievements (and therefore Primogems) for reaching friendship level 10 with 4/8/16 different characters. Check out the [Genshin Impact wiki](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Friendship_Level) for complete information on friendship levels.

As far as I know friendship level has no effect on the character's combat ability/stats.

Comment: But except that, is there any gifts for going to level 10 with a character? Like any items (like the Wish keys) or thing like that? If you don't care about the lore thingies, is there any reason to get a character to level 10?

Comment: @Fredy31 You don't receive any items/currency/wishes for reaching level 10, only the namecard. If you don't care about that and aren't interested in the characters' lore and interactions then you can pretty much ignore friendship level entirely in its current state.

Comment: One additional thing friendship level affects is the available expressions a character can make in photo mode, only the first expression is unlocked by default and the remaining 2 need higher friendship level to unlock. There is also the tangentially related achievements for getting friendship level 10 with 4/8/16 characters for 35 primos altogether. Would you consider editing to put a link to the wiki RE: friendship levels (https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Friendship_Level) as reference

Comment: Ah yeah, good points. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Friendship levels gives you the lore and the story of this world presented in an interesting way like voice lines and how they feel about stuff. The friendship mechanic mostly focuses characters lore. Each character has a story, origin, and special life lessons. So, every one of them gets a different friendship level. As of right now it does not affect combat at all.